# How to properly use html-to-react?

Tags: html, reactjs, nodes, parent-child, treenode

so i am learning about this package html-to-react, and for the most part, i understand it. However, their is a piece of code i just cannot seem to be able to get my head around. The code is:

```
var React = require('react');
var HtmlToReact = require('html-to-react');
var HtmlToReactParser = require('html-to-react').Parser;

var htmlToReactParser = new HtmlToReactParser();
var htmlInput = '<div><div data-test="foo"><p>Text</p><p>Text</p></div></div>';
var htmlExpected = '<div><div data-test="foo"><h1>Heading</h1></div></div>';

var isValidNode = function () {
  return true;
};
 
var processNodeDefinitions = new HtmlToReact.ProcessNodeDefinitions(React);
 
// Order matters. Instructions are processed in
// the order they're defined
var processingInstructions = [
  {
    // This is REQUIRED, it tells the parser
    // that we want to insert our React
    // component as a child
    replaceChildren: true,
    shouldProcessNode: function (node) {
      return node.attribs && node.attribs['data-test'] === 'foo';
    },
    processNode: function (node, children, index) {
      return React.createElement('h1', {key: index,}, 'Heading');
    }
  },
  {
    // Anything else
    shouldProcessNode: function (node) {
      return true;
    },
    processNode: processNodeDefinitions.processDefaultNode,
  },
]; 

var reactComponent = htmlToReactParser.parseWithInstructions(
htmlInput, isValidNode, processingInstructions);
var reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
reactComponent);
assert.equal(reactHtml, htmlExpected);
```

The code i don't understand is the:

```
shouldProcessNode: function (node) {
  return node.attribs && node.attribs['data-test'] === 'foo';
},
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Firstly the function is passed in hash with key 'shouldProceessNode'. This function returns either true or false. The return statement checks if node has field attribs and than check if 'data-test' key has value set to 'foo'. This condition return false if node object is missing attribute 'attribs' or if value for 'data-test' is not equal to 'foo'. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Hi, thank you sir, that makes complete sense, i now understand. Appreciate it

Comment: Hi, so I have been using this package, and a problem I am running in to is, I cannot seem to reference the text in my HTML code. So what I mean is, the text that is not surrounded by a div or a h1 and that does not have attribute or anything. Do you know of anyway I can reference that text? Thank you

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html this should help to reference the html DOM objects and use it React components. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.